# Python - Global Name is not defined

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I promise I have read through the other versions of this question, but I was unable to find a relevant one to my situation. If there is one, I apologize, I've been staring at this for a few hours now.

I've been toying with this a lot and actually got results on one version, so know it's close.

The 'start_URLs' variable is defined as a list prior to the function, but for some reason doesn't register on the global/module level.

Here is the exact error: for listing_url_list in start_urls:
NameError: global name 'start_urls' is not defined

```
import time
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scraper1.items import scraper1Item

from scraper1 import csvmodule

absolute_pos = './/*[@id="xpath"]/td/@class'

class spider1(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ugh'
    allowed_domains = ["ugh.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.website.link.1",
        "http://www.website.link.2",
        "http://www.website.link.3"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        Select = Selector(response)
        listing_url_list = Select.xpath('.//*[@id="xpath"]/li/div/a/@href').extract()
        for listing_url_list in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(listing_url, callback=self.parselisting, dont_filter=True)

    def parselisting(self, response):
        ResultsDict = scraper1Item()
        Select = Selector(response)
        ResultsDict['absolute_pos'] = Select.xpath(absolute_pos).extract()
        ResultsDict['listing_url'] = response.url
        return ResultsDict
```

Comment: `self.start_urls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your `start_requests()` method:

- you meant to use `listing_url_list` instead of `start_urls`
- you meant to use `listing_url` instead of `listing_url_list` as a loop variable
- there is no need to instantiate `Selector` - use [`response.xpath()` shortcut](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1) directly

Fixed version:

```
def parse(self, response):
    listing_url_list = response.xpath('.//*[@id="xpath"]/li/div/a/@href').extract()
    for listing_url in listing_url_list:
        yield scrapy.Request(listing_url, callback=self.parselisting, dont_filter=True)
```

---

As a side note, I think you don't need `CrawlSpider` and can actually use a regular [`scrapy.Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider), since you are not actually using `rules` with link extractors.

Comment: know any good reading on using response. vs the selector(response)?

Comment: @Winklevoss333 don't have anything better than the link I've posted - the documentation page contains multiple examples. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

use `spider1.start_urls` instead of just `start_urls`.

Comment: Crap, both spider1.start_urls and self.start_urls fix the immediate problem, but then yield an issue with the listing_url not being defined...

Comment: @Winklevoss333 shouldn't it be `listing_url_list`?